# Is it possible to merge hotfix branch to both develop and main branch in Github?

Tags: github, pull-request, git-flow

I'm now using gitflow strategy and github as a remote repository.

Recently I encountered a problem of merging hotfix PRs into both develop and main branch.

It seems the Github supports only one target branch for a PR and doesn't know whether a branch is feature or hotfix.

Currently, I just close PR and merge them in local and push it to the remote.

Is anybody have nice idea or github feature I can use to merge a hotfix branch to both develop and main branch at the same time?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be very helpful for me if you share the reason I got a minus vote cause I want to improve my question and not get another minus again 

Comment: PR is just UI for `git merge`, right? AFAIK you can `merge` only into one branch at a time, so the same way you can create a PR for merging into one branch. The same way as you merge it manually on localhost (ie. running multiple/another `git merge`), the same way you can create another PR into the other branch, no? Also I sense there is a problem that both "target" branches can diverge, so the identical PR would contain more/different commits when targeting the "other" branch. So I dont see how this would really work.

Comment: There are some Git GUI such as Sourcetree which, with Gitflow, support merging a hotfix branch to both main and develop branch if the hotfix is finished. But I don't know exactly how Gitflow doing it. If I find how it does and some solution to this, I'll let you know. 

Your comment helped me. Thank you yedpodtrzitko.

Comment: Sure you can merge a branch into multiple different branches, but that is multiple separate operations. If I understand your question correctly you want to merge one branch into multiple branches at the same time. That is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that One PR = One merge. All you need are two separate PRs, one to merge `hotfix` into `main`, and another to merge `hotfix` into `develop`. Regarding the code reviews, it's best for a [Git Flow Hotfix branch](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/#hotfix-branches) to also be a protected branch, which itself requires a code review. For example:

1. When you realize you need a hotfix, you create a branch off of `main`, for example `hotfix-1.2.3` (or `hotfix/1.2.3`). Protect the branch so that PRs are required to merge into it, just like for `develop` and `main`.
2. Use a normal PR to merge a feature branch with the hotfix commit(s) into the `hotfix` branch.
3. Test the `hotfix` branch.
4. Deploy the hotfix, and merge `hotfix` into `main` and also into `develop`. These 2 merges are "Git Flow" merges and can possibly be automated and bypass the PR process. Or you can create 2 more PRs for the two merges. Note that these 2 PRs do not require regular code reviews like the PR in step #2. Since these PRs *could* be automated, if you need a human to approve, they can likely just do a quick sanity check that the merges are correct.

Regarding:

> Currently, I just close PR and merge them in local and push it to the remote.

Doing that will work, and is kind of the same thing as automating the 2 merges as described in step #4. If you go that route I would recommend scripting it so that it's repeatable and less prone to error. Note that when you have merge conflicts, you will need to manually intervene regardless.

**Tip:** When using Git Flow, my personal preference when completing both `release` and `hotfix` branches, is to first merge them into `main`, and then merge `main` into `develop` (instead of also merging the release or hotfix branch into `develop`). Doing this is functionally equivalent, except that the merge commit that goes on `main` gets brought down to `develop` immediately, instead of with the next `hotfix`. It's slightly cleaner this way and it also means that `develop` and/or your `release` branches are always fully up to date with `main`, in both *state* and *commits*. (Doing it the way Git Flow is documented only brings the *state* up to date.)

Comment: Sorry for late comment and thank you for your answer @TTT. 

I couldn't get what you mean by `"Doing that will work, and is kind of the same thing as automating the 2 merges as described in step #4."` as it seems exactly same for me. In #4, you said there should be 2 merges but it can not be done without 2 PRs in Github and I understand it as doing it in local and push the branches to the remote which is what I wrote in the question. Please let me know if there are any other routes.

Comment: @dontStayHere Note a single PR can only do one merge, so to do 2 merges you need 2 PRs. The reason I said that automating the merges is basically the same as doing what you're doing, is because if you automate it, you'll press a button and some copy of the repo on some server (e.g. GitHub actions, etc) will fetch the latest, switch to `main`, merge in `hotfix`, push `main`, switch to `develop`, merge in `hotfix`, push `develop`, and it would be done in such a way that it could bypass PRs (if the branches are protected). You're basically doing those steps manually but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

In general, merging the same PR into multiple branches at the same time is a very bad idea.

The only exception is marking one of the PR's as a Draft with some `do-not-merge` tag - in order to trigger a CI pass on the changes.

---

There are two major issues with this:

### Inconsistent History

Merging the same set of changes into multiple branches at the same time - instead of doing it sequentially, ie. landing in one branch first - creates two distinct commits that are not linked to one another.

This makes it a lot harder for people to figure out whether a particular fix went into a particular branch.

Even more so in the rare case that something went terribly wrong and the fix needs to be reverted.

### Split Code Review

If you're in a bigger organization that does peer code review, chances are that reviews - and comments / questions - could get split between the two PR's.

You might even waste other people's time if for instance one of your PR got approved after addressing a few comments - and another person who didn't see that reviews the other version.

---

So it's much better to first land your changes in one branch - which would typically be your development branch - then create a PR that merges these already-merged changes into the other branch.

The way you do that is to first merge your PR into the development branch.

Then, create an integration branch off of current master, `git cherry-pick` the commit that merged your changes into the development branch (you might want to use `git cherry-pick -x` and possibly edit the commit message to include a link to that merged PR), then create a PR of that and include a link to the previous PR in the description.

It is a little bit of extra work and not really needed for small projects, but once your project grows, it will become quite important.

Comment: Sorry for the DV here, but it looks like you missed the Git Flow tag. Merging into two branches is actually *required*. It also doesn't require cherry-picking since you should use 2 separate `--no-ff` merges. I agree with parts of this answer in general though, but it isn't relevant to this question.